# column formula error preventing subsite creation

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column-formula, sub-site

When attempting to add subsite in Classic view SharePoint online, I receive - "Sorry, something went wrong. The formula refers to a column that does not exist.  Check the formula for spelling mistakes or change the non-existing column to an existing column."  Thoughts?

Comment: Are you creating a new subsite using old site template? What is the name of a column which is shown in error?

Comment: You need to check the Calculated column in the site mentioned in the error message if any, or go through all the Calculated columns to see if the formulas all work well. Can you provide detailed information on this site?